# selfupdate for Macports, install packages via macports

Tags: macports

`    Macports selfupdate is failing on Mac OS 10.9.5 installed with Xcode(6.2) and commandline tools.I have tried with 2 versions of macports, 2.3.0 and 2.3.3.
    $ port -v
    MacPorts 2.3.0

```
1. Error is rsync fails to connect to sources on macports.org. I have the firewall turned off on the mac machine though. I was looking for https://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar  on browser, the path does not exist. It may the sources are not available for rsync to sync them to local system. please advise on how to perform port selfupdate.

$ sudo /usr/bin/port -v selfupdate
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Connection refused (61)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
Exit code: 10
Error: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: /usr/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed

2. packages are not found using port command
$ sudo port -v install samba3
Error: Port samba3 not found

Thanks in advance.`
```

Answer (score 1):

RSYNC isn't HTTP, opening the URL using HTTP does not give you the same result, because the HTTP server at rsync.macports.org does not serve the file you requested.

Your question is a FAQ at http://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#selfupdatefails:

> **What do I do if port selfupdate doesn't work or the rsync server refuses connections?**
>
> First try `sudo port -d selfupdate` to get all errors to display. If your connection to the rsync server fails you may get blocked by a firewall or other network control software.
>
> Some firewalls, such as PeerGuardian, block connections to certain corporate IP addresses as a way to prevent software from "phoning home" and violating your privacy. Our main rsync server is hosted by Apple Inc. Self updating requires an rsync connection to download files, but this will be blocked. In order to work around this, you need to temporarily disable or white-list rsync.macports.org. Another alternative is to use [another mirror](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Mirrors) that is not hosted by Apple.
>
> The black list entry is all of Apple Inc's subnet, which is 17.0.0.0/8. Disable this or create a white-list exception for rsync.macports.org. PeerGuardian will filter your network connections even if it is not actively running as an application. It is possible to disable PeerGuardian before running a selfupdate command by typing the following command in Terminal, but make sure you stop all processes associated with PeerGuardian before doing this.
>
> `sudo kextunload -b xxx.qnation.PeerGuardian`
>
> If you run LittleSnitch, create a rule for rsync (`/usr/bin/rsync`) that allows connections to server hostname `rsync.macports.org`, port 873 (rsync), protocol 6 (TCP). Make sure the rule is enabled.
>
> If getting through a firewall is not a possibility, there are other methods you can use which are a bit more manual:
>
> - [You can sync your port tree using Subversion](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/SyncingWithSVN)
> - [You can download a tarball, built daily, and update with that](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/PortTreeTarball)